cgohlke gdal wheels - early version location
Problem:
I recently found out that cgohlke gdal wheel site was taken down and redirected to a github repo. Though, I am unable to locate gdal.whl files that predate v2023.1.4 (3.6.1), even though PyPl goes all the way back to 1.5.0. Could someone point me to the location where the additional .whl files are located?
Purpose:
I typically pip install gdal .whl files rather than conda forge because I constantly run into dependency issues (normally geopandas), especially if I am trying to recreate a env that uses a specific version of gdal.
Alternate Solution:
I can download a gdal-version.tar.gz file, but am unsure how to install from there. For example, here is an image of gdal 3.2.1. How would I install this specific version into my conda env?


Your "gdal-version.tar.gz file" is a source archive. It contains C++ code that needs to be compiled, which is not a simple process if you're unfamiliar with it.

Rather than that alternate solution, is there a site for earlier .whl files?
